# Is it possible to calculate MAPE for time series just for training data?

Tags: r, time, series

Example below calculates MAPE using training set and test set
Is it possible to calculate MAPE just for training data?
x is a numeric vector
y is a ts data

```
    y<-x %>% ts(start=c(1988,1),end=c(2021,3), frequency =12)
```

Training set: start = 01/1988, end=12/2000
Testing set:   start = 01/2000, end=12/2005

```
    y.train=window(y, end=c(2000,12)) 
    y.test=window(y, start=c(2000,1), end=c(2005,12))
    
    m1F = snaive(y.train, h=length(y.test), level=F)
```

accuracy metrics calculates MAPE

```
    accuracy(m1F, y.test)[,c(2,5)]
```

#Is it possible to calculate MAPE just for training data?

Comment: [Yes, it is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65443/171783). All you need is the model forecasts of the training data set. Also, if the training data ends 12/2000, shouldn't the test data start 1/2001?

Comment: use `Metrics::mape`  function